# SQL Exists and Not Exists

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Since I'am new to SQL, I'm having some troubles understanding the `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS`.

I have these tables:

Table Aluno:

```
+----+----------------+--------------------+
| id | nome           | email              |
+----+----------------+--------------------+
|  1 | João da Silva  | joao@dasilva.com   |
|  2 | Frederico José | fred@jose.com      |
|  3 | Alberto Santos | alberto@santos.com |
|  4 | Renata Alonso  | renata@alonso.com  |
|  5 | Paulo da Silva | paulo@dasilva.com  |
+----+----------------+--------------------+
```

Table Matricula

```
+----+----------+----------+---------------------+---------+
| id | aluno_id | curso_id | data                | tipo    |
+----+----------+----------+---------------------+---------+
|  1 |        1 |        1 | 2013-11-25 16:16:05 | PAGA_PF |
|  2 |        2 |        1 | 2013-05-25 16:16:25 | PAGA_PJ |
|  3 |        3 |        3 | 2013-07-21 16:16:30 | PAGA_PF |
|  4 |        4 |        4 | 2013-11-15 16:15:35 | PAGA_PK |
|  5 |        2 |        2 | 2012-01-04 00:00:00 | PAGA_PJ |
+----+----------+----------+---------------------+---------+
```

Running this query:

```
select a.nome from Aluno a where not exists(select m.id from Matricula m where m.aluno_id = a.id and m.data < now() - interval 46 month);
```

I got this result:

```
+----------------+
| nome           |
+----------------+
| João da Silva  |
| Renata Alonso  |
| Paulo da Silva |
+----------------+
```

The question is: how `NOT EXISTS` subquery is `TRUE` if the subquery's select statement returns more than `0` rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NOT EXISTS` subquery is true for Frederico and Alberto, but false for the other three. This is correct, because there is no row in the Matricula table that is both is linked to Aluno 1, 4, or 5 and has a date in the last 46 months.